Assert array not present with each match
After upgrade to latest version of karate (1.1.0 to 1.4.1) this line is no longer working
And Match each response[*].foos[*].bars == "#notpresent"

foos and bars are arrays
I want to assert that in foos array each object do not contain an array field bars
It failed
match failed: EACH_EQUALS
  $ | match each failed, empty array / list (LIST:STRING)
  []
  '#notpresent'


Please read the release notes: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/releases/tag/v1.4.1
I think your assertion is wrong and the change actually forces you to correct your test. I recommend something like this:
* match each response.foos !contains { bars: '#present' }

If you really want to revert to the old behavior (which I don't think is right in your case) you can do this:
* configure matchEachEmptyAllowed = true

